# Hibernate.cfg.xml not found after deploy the web app to heroku

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, maven, heroku

After deploying a web application with maven to heroku cloud, I get log error:

> app[web.1]: org.hibernate.HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found.

The web application running locally correctly, but on the cloud not.
This is my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate  Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todoitemsdb
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!-- Mapping files -->
    <mapping class="il.ac.hit.model.User" resource="todoitems.xml"/>
    <mapping class="il.ac.hit.model.ToDoItem" resource="users.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `hibernate.cfg.xml` is bundled into your jar like this:

```
your-app.jar\hibernate.cfg.xml
```

That's where Hibernate tries to locate the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I had my hibernate.cfg.xml under resources under a folder config

Changing the below line

```
cfg.configure("./config/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

to

```
cfg.configure("config/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

worked.